# APK stopped working after minify, uglify - Code runs on : 'ionic serve --lab' and and 'ionic run android -l --debug' but not on 'ionic build android'

Tags: angularjs, exception, ionic-framework

I was following the [tutorial to make a production ready ionic app](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/production-ready-apps-with-ionic-framework). I wanted to uglify my js.
All works great except for 'ionic build android' generates an apk, installing which the app doesn't run. The same code runs with 'ionic serve --lab' and 'ionic run android'. Please help.

**Code runs on : ‘ionic serve –lab’ and and 'ionic run android -l --debug’ but not on 'ionic build android’**

I added the following code for exception handling, is there a better way to know what run-time exception might cause something like this?

```js
// catch exceptions out of angular
window.onerror = function(message, url, line, col, error) {
  var debug = true;
  var stopPropagation = debug ? false : true;
  var data = {
    type: 'javascript',
    url: window.location.hash,
    localtime: Date.now()
  };
  if (message) {
    data.message = message;
  }
  if (url) {
    data.fileName = url;
  }
  if (line) {
    data.lineNumber = line;
  }
  if (col) {
    data.columnNumber = col;
  }
  if (error) {
    if (error.name) {
      data.name = error.name;
    }
    if (error.stack) {
      data.stack = error.stack;
    }
  }

  if (debug) {
    console.log('exception', data);
    window.alert('Error: ' + data.message);
  } else {
    track('exception', data);
  }
  return stopPropagation;
};
```

**EDIT 1**
I got this error on running adb logcat:

```
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/css/social-icons.css
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/css/font-awesome.css
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/css/style-chetan.css
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/css/tabSlideBox.css
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/app.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/controllers.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/services.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/openfb.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/ngopenfb.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/collide.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/ionic.tdcards.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/mfb-directive.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/ng-cordova-oauth.min.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/ng-cordova.min.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/facebookConnectPlugin.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/tabSlideBox.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/templates.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/dist/dist_js/app/ng-tags-input.js
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/css/ng-tags-input.bootstrap.css
E/AndroidProtocolHandler( 3622): Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset
/www/css/ng-tags-input.css
```

My apk doesn't have these files, as I have installed    npm install gulp-useref --save-dev as mentioned in the tutorial. This builds all css and js to one single file.
Also inside the apk in assets/ww now I have only two folders dist_js and dist_css

Comment: You can try and unzip the apk and see if the structure is still there.

Comment: I did that, instead of the css and js folders, I now have a dist_js and dist_css, I don't understand why the exceptional handling is not working.

Comment: Probably it does not work cause some of the scripts cannot be loaded and the event is not triggered. It's a tough problem and not easy to debug.

Comment: it worked well before I tried the uglifying tutotial. Your right it seems that it's not able to locate the files. But now I don't know why is looking for the files at these file locations.. `css` and `dist` under assets\www, whereas I now have only dist_js and dist_css here

Comment: it seems that the gulp task `ng_annotate`. it should change the references in the index.html file referencing the new path: `dist/dist_js/`.

Comment: I'm totally new to this, can you please elaborate.. Do you mean that, I should change the reference path in gulpfile.js?

Comment: if you go to the [Enable ng-strict-di](https://www.airpair.com/ionic-framework/posts/production-ready-apps-with-ionic-framework#-a-name-enable-ng-strict-di-enable-ng-strict-di-a-) it gives you details of how things should work. To be honest with you I tried following that guide but it was too complicated cause you have gulp tasks and node tasks. I ended up doing everything with node tasks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89844/discussion-between-pavitar-and-leftyx).

Comment: Did you try to follow my suggestion?

Comment: @LeftyX Your suggestion is great & it lead me to my solution. I thought I should share that as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @LeftyX 's suggestion to change the hooks js files, lead me to my solution. Apparently I had to move a few more files which were not a part of the default steps mentioned in the tutorial. But that was just because my structure was different. i.e I had moved index.html content to main.html and index.html had a script tag like this

```html
<script>
  window.location = './main.html';
</script>
```

So to solve it I added the following to `040_move_dist_files_to_platforms.js` file :

```
var androidPlatformsDir_www_css = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android/assets/www/dist_css');
var androidPlatformsDir_www_main = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../platforms/android/assets/www/main.html');
mv(androidPlatformsDir_dist_main, androidPlatformsDir_www_main, function(err) {
  if(typeof err != 'undefined')
  {
    console.log("err");
    console.log(err);
    console.log("ERROR when moving main.html file to Android platform");
  }
  else
  {
    console.log("main.html file moved OK to Android platform");
  }
});
```

Also I renamed text 'index.html' to 'main.html' in 010_add_platform_class.js

One more problem that I noticed an error in one of my js files within the block

```
<!-- build:js dist_js/app.js -->
```

commenting that helped.

Comment: Glad I've helped, in a way. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I followed that tutorial but at some point I gave up as it was mixing too many different different tasks: gulp and node.

My personal opinion is the hooks should be responsible to prepare the folders for the final build.

I came up with this solution which works pretty well but requires some configuration. Having said that even the solution proposed in that article requires some sort of defining folders for different gulp tasks.

First of all you need to install a few package:

```
npm install jshint --save-dev
npm install async --save-dev
npm install htmlparser2 --save-dev
npm install concat-with-sourcemaps --save-dev
npm install uglify-js --save-dev
npm install clean-css --save-dev
npm install ng-annotate --save-dev
npm install node-useref --save-dev
```

then you need to copy these hooks in the `hooks` folder. 
You should have this `after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js` javascript file already.

[before_prepare\02_jshint.js](https://gist.github.com/Leftyx/93f22392ccc0165fcc86) must be copied in the folder `before_prepare` inside hooks. If you don't have that folder, just create it.

[after_prepare\011_move_fonts_to_root.js](https://gist.github.com/Leftyx/354ab934f7e44457ac54) must be copied in the folder `after_prepare`.

[after_prepare\012_concat_files_in_index.js](https://gist.github.com/Leftyx/c005ccc382c2ef4cafb1) must be copied in the folder `after_prepare`.

[after_prepare\013_unused_folders_delete.js](https://gist.github.com/Leftyx/9abb24c07dbbeb56b4ee) must be copied in the folder `after_prepare`.

[after_prepare\014_uglify.js](https://gist.github.com/Leftyx/186e01403dfe2f644741) must be copied in the folder `after_prepare`.

[after_prepare\015_prepare_index_html.js](https://gist.github.com/Leftyx/99883d737a865341d153) must be copied in the folder `after_prepare`.

I'll try to explain what all these scripts should do.

`02_jshint.js` will validated the javascripts in your application.

You can edit that file and change or add other javascripts folders to this array:

```
var foldersToProcess = [
    'js'
];
```

I am doing this as I don't have all main application's js files in the same place.

`011_move_fonts_to_root.js` move all the fonts in a folder called `fonts` in the root of your app.
I have to do this task as at some point I am going to remove all the `lib` folder, which is a hell of a lot of weight for your app during release.

Again in that file there's an array of folder:

```
var foldersWithFontsToMove = [
  'lib/ionic/fonts'
];
```

where you can add other fonts folders you want to move to the root `fonts`.

`012_concat_files_in_index.js` parses the html file `index.html` and finds all the references to the js and css files and concatenate all those files in just 2 documents: `app.js` and `app.css`.

These 2 bundles will contain all the js files of your app included the ionic bundles.

NOTE: `cordova.js` won't be touched cause it's better like this.

Here you can adjust things working with these 4 variables:

```
var appConcatFolder = 'app';
var appConcatFile = 'app.js';
var cssConcatFolder = 'css';
var cssConcatFile = 'app.css';
```

`appConcatFolder` is the folder which will contain the bundle for the js file.
`appConcatFile` is the name of the js bundle.
`cssConcatFolder` is the folder which will contain the bundle for the js file
`cssConcatFile` is the name of the css bundle.

`013_unused_folders_delete.js` will delete all the unused folders.
Since we're moving stuff around there no need to have those folders copied in our final app.

You can configure it adding or removing path to this array:

```
var foldersToRemove = [
  'lib',
  'js'
];
```

Since we've moved all the js files in the folder app (in the root) we don't need the `js` folder any more. We get rid of the `lib` folder where all the ionic stuff as been put.

`014_uglify.js` uglifies and minifies the js file and the css bundles.

You can change this file updating this array:

```
var foldersToProcess = [ 
    'app',
    'css'
];
```

This array contains the folders where the css bundle; the other folder is the js bundle folder.

`015_prepare_index_html.js` will use `node-useref` to parse our `index.html` file and replace the scripts and css with our bundles.

To configure this task you have to change your index.html file adding these sections:

```
<!-- build:css css/app.css -->

<!-- endbuild -->
```

so your index.html could look like this:

```
<!-- build:css css/app.css -->
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js app/app.js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

if you want to find out more about `node-useref` you can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-useref).

Now, with all these scripts in place you should be able to run:

```
ionic build --release [platform]
```

or my custom `ionic run --runrelease`.

You will see lot of things happening as I write in the console quite a lot of info.

At the end of the process you should find this folder structure in your apk:

[image]

where you will find your compressed, minified and uglified files and your `index.html` with the new references.